# Angular doesn't work when defining a service and factory separately

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to write a simple angular service and a factory like below:

**html:**

```
<div ng-controller="mycontroller">
    {{saycheese}}
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.service('myservice', function() {
    this.sayHello = function() {
        return "from service";
    };
});

myApp.factory('myfactory', function() {
    return {
        sayHello: function() {
            return "from factory!"
        }
    };
});

//defining a controller over here      
myapp.controller("mycontroller", ["myfactory", "myservice", function(myfactory, myservice) {

    $scope.saycheese = [
        myfactory.sayHello(),
        myservice.sayHello()
        ];

}]);
```

But the `JSFiddle` still just displays `{{saycheese}}` instead of angular mapping the function.

Link to my fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/PxdSP/3047/

Can you point me where am I going wrong in this case ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several syntax errors in your code, and checking the console would have helped without questioning the SO. Here's one possible way to write the controller ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7kL1n4pb/)):

```
myApp.controller("mycontroller", ["$scope", "myfactory", "myservice", 
   function($scope, myfactory, myservice) {
     $scope.saycheese = [
        myfactory.sayHello(),
        myservice.sayHello()
     ];
}]);
```

Apart from obvious fix `myapp => myApp` (variable names are case-sensitive in JavaScript), `$scope` should be passed into controller as an argument (and mentioned as its dependency if using arrayed - proper - form of controller definition, as you did) before you can access it. Otherwise you just get `ReferenceError: $scope is not defined` exception when controller code is invoked.

Comment: Just started with angular. Didn't know about console checking. Got it now. :)

Answer (score 1):

Couple things:

1. `myapp.controller(...)` should be `myApp.controller(...)`
2. You need to inject `$scope` in your controller.

Fixed controller:

```
myApp.controller("mycontroller", ["myfactory", "myservice", "$scope", function(myfactory, myservice, $scope) {
    $scope.saycheese = [
        myfactory.sayHello(),
        myservice.sayHello()
    ];
}]);
```